# XSD relation between classes, + hierarchy relation

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have some xml in the following format where in the group state can either be states of true false as defined in definition state, or use another group with one of it's values.

How can I use xsd for this relation contsraint - using ID and IDref solved for the definition and group name, but how do I constrain that the value of the group is really a value as defined in the group?

Also is there any way to distinguish between the ID, in case using definition the value should be true / false string. in case using another group state should be one of its defined state?

```
  <Definitions>
    <Definition Name="Name1"/>
    <Definition Name="Name2"  />
  </Definitions>

  <ValueGrps>
    <Group Name="grp1">
      <ComplexState Name="state1">
        <State Name="Name1" Value="true" />
        <State Name="Name2" Value="true" />
      </ComplexState>
      <ComplexState Name="state2">
        <State Name="Name1" Value="false" />
        <State Name="Name2" Value="true" />
      </ComplexState>
    </Group>
    <Group Name="grp2">
      <ComplexState Name="state1">
        <State Name="grp1" Value="state1" />           
      </ComplexState>
    </Group>      
  </ValueGrps>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD 1.0 alone cannot help you here. You could apply Schematron for sure; there is an XSLT 1.0 implementation which works on .NET (since you've indicated C#).

XSD 1.1 has built in support for what you need. However, XSD 1.1 is poorly supported on .NET as in you either buy Saxon's EE for NET OR you use IKVM to "port" XercesJ on .NET (I've done it and it works). You would have issues, in an open environment, to have other people using XSD 1.1 schemas.

If this is a new design, I would probably also change some of the design... for example, a `State` referencing a group is not the same as a `State` referencing a Definition - I would then define different content models for the different reference types. I would also drop ID/IDREF in favour of key(unique)/keyref. I am attaching an example below which would work with the provided XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="root">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Definitions">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Definition">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ValueGrps">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Group">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ComplexState">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="State">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                              <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                              <xsd:attribute name="Value" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                            </xsd:complexType>
                          </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:key name="PK_1">
        <xsd:selector xpath="Definitions/Definition|ValueGrps/Group"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@Name"/>      
    </xsd:key>
    <xsd:keyref name="FK_1" refer="PK_1">
        <xsd:selector xpath="ValueGrps/Group/ComplexState/State"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@Name"/>
    </xsd:keyref>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```